# How to change a Ruby Class Variable value

Tags: ruby, class-variables

I'm new to Ruby and I what I want to do is the following

```
class WS< ActiveRecord::Base
  @@SequenceNumber = 0

  def self.oper1
    @@SequenceNumber = 2
  end

  def self.oper2
   @@SequenceNumber += 1 
   puts @@SequenceNumber.to_s
  end

  def self.oper3
   puts @@SequenceNumber.to_s
  end
end
```

If I do something like:

```
WS.oper1
WS.oper2
WS.oper3
```

I get the following output:

```
3
2
```

Why isn't my @@SequenceNumber += 1 working? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works just fine:

```
class WS
  @@sequence_number = 0

  def self.oper1
    @@sequence_number = 2
  end

  def self.oper2
   puts @@sequence_number += 1
  end

  def self.oper3
   puts @@sequence_number
  end
end

WS.oper3
# 0

WS.oper1
WS.oper2
# 3

WS.oper3
# 3
```

[Note: I took the liberty of Rubyfying your code a little bit.]

Answer (score -5):

This is working at expected:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should type this all out instead as it's hard to read this.